# how to show an icon based on the icon name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am fetching pokemon data from API. and based on the pokemon types I want to show an icon of that type. and types could be two in that case I need to show two icons in the pokemon card.  I am using string literal to display the cards. how can I make another map function inside the string literal? my approach is below but I wasn't successful to show two icons in the cards. how can I show two icons as types are in some pokemon cards two?

```js
const cards = document.querySelector(".cards");
const error = document.querySelector(".err");
const search = document.querySelector("#search");
const result = document.querySelector("#result");
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".genButton");
const card2 = document.querySelector(".card2");
let icon;

let generations = [{
    limit: 151,
    offset: 0
  },
  {
    limit: 100,
    offset: 151
  },
  {
    limit: 135,
    offset: 251
  },
  {
    limit: 107,
    offset: 386
  },
  {
    limit: 156,
    offset: 493
  },
  {
    limit: 72,
    offset: 649
  },
  {
    limit: 88,
    offset: 721
  },
  {
    limit: 96,
    offset: 809
  },
  {
    limit: 3,
    offset: 905
  },
];
const getTypeImg = (type) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "bug":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/Pok%C3%A9mon_Bug_Type_Icon.svg";
    case "dark":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/Pok%C3%A9mon_Dark_Type_Icon.svg";
    case "ghost":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Pok%C3%A9mon_Ghost_Type_Icon.svg";
    case "grass":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Pok%C3%A9mon_Grass_Type_Icon.svg";
    case "dragon":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/Pok%C3%A9mon_Dragon_Type_Icon.svg";
    case "electric":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Pok%C3%A9mon_Electric_Type_Icon.svg";
    case "fairy":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Pok%C3%A9mon_Fairy_Type_Icon.svg";
    case "fighting":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Pok%C3%A9mon_Fighting_Type_Icon.svg";
    case "fire":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Pok%C3%A9mon_Fire_Type_Icon.svg";
    case "flying":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/Pok%C3%A9mon_Flying_Type_Icon.svg";
    case "ground":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8d/Pok%C3%A9mon_Ground_Type_Icon.svg";
    case "ice":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/Pok%C3%A9mon_Ice_Type_Icon.svg";
    case "normal":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Pok%C3%A9mon_Normal_Type_Icon.svg";
    case "poison":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Pok%C3%A9mon_Poison_Type_Icon.svg";
    case "psychic":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Pok%C3%A9mon_Psychic_Type_Icon.svg";
    case "rock":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bb/Pok%C3%A9mon_Rock_Type_Icon.svg";
    case "steel":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/Pok%C3%A9mon_Steel_Type_Icon.svg";
    case "water":
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0b/Pok%C3%A9mon_Water_Type_Icon.svg";
    default:
      return "#";
  }
};

search.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  let input = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  const pokeCards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
  pokeCards.forEach((element) => {
    let pokeManName = element.children[1].children[0].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
    const isVisible = pokeManName.includes(input);
    element.classList.toggle("hide", !isVisible);
  });
});

const displayPokemon = (pokemonss) => {
  cards.innerHTML = "";
  Promise.all(pokemonss).then((result) => {
    result.map((data) => {
      cards.innerHTML += `<div class="card">
          <div class="imgContainer">
            <img src=${
              data.sprites.other["official-artwork"].front_default
            } alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="infoConatiner">
            <p>${data.name[0].toUpperCase() + data.name.slice(1)}</p>
           <img src="${data.types.map((type) => getTypeImg(type.type.name))}" />
         
          </div>
        </div>`;
    });
  });
};

const fetchPokemons = async(btn) => {
  const response = await fetch(
      `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=${generations[btn].limit}&offset=${generations[btn].offset}`
    )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => data.results);

  const pokemons = await response.map((poke) => {
    return fetch(poke.url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => data);
  });

  displayPokemon(pokemons);
  setTimeout(() => {
    result.innerHTML = `${generations[btn].limit} pokemons were found...`;
    search.style.visibility = "visible";
  }, 1000);
};

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  const btn = button.getAttribute("data-value");
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    fetchPokemons(btn);
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="heading">
        <h1>Pokedex</h1>
        <div class="genButtons">
          <button class="genButton" data-value="0">Gen 1</button>
          <button class="genButton" data-value="1">Gen 2</button>
          <button class="genButton" data-value="2">Gen 3</button>
          <button class="genButton" data-value="3">Gen 4</button>
          <button class="genButton" data-value="4">Gen 5</button>
          <button class="genButton" data-value="5">Gen 6</button>
          <button class="genButton" data-value="6">Gen 7</button>
          <button class="genButton" data-value="7">Gen 8</button>
        </div>
        <div class="msg">
          <p id="result">To see pokemons, choose generations first....</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="Search pokemons" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="err"></div>
      <div class="cards"></div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>
```

Comment: without html it's hard to tell

Comment: i have added html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple images. In `displayPokemon` instead of
`<img src="${data.types.map((type) => getTypeImg(type.type.name))}" />`, map over the array and create an `img` for each of them.

```js
<div class="infoConatiner">
  <p>${data.name[0].toUpperCase() + data.name.slice(1)}</p>
  ${data.types.map((type) => 
    `<img src="${getTypeImg(type.type.name)}" />`
  ).join('')}
</div>
```

You might want to wrap the images in a `div` and position them with `display: flex`, but it's up to you how you want to arrange the icons.

Comment: Thank you so much that definitely works but can you please describe a bit how this is working? a bit about this codes '<img src="' + getTypeImg(type.type.name) + '"/>').join('')

Comment: Sure, an image can only have one `src`, so instead of creating one image with multiple sources, we have to create multiple images for each of the source images. That's why we're creating an `img` tag inside of `map`. This results in an array of strings, which we have to concatenate with `join`.
I could have used a template string inside of `map`, I'm updating the answer to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: So for a pokemon that has 2 types, it would generate the following HTML: `<img src="some-type.svg" /><img src="some-other-type.svg />`, which is the two `img`s returned by map, `join`ed by an empty string. This would also work for any arbitrary number of types.

If my solution helped, please consider marking it as an accepted answer.